# Scaling SVG in HTML5 or in svg file or from css

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to show full SVG image with dynamic width and height from html or CSS

for example: 
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWgXmj

```
<svg with="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
```

Not showing full SVG image

Comment: Full size? Like 100% width and height?

Comment: increase the viewBox values till all the image is visible if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your svg definition, `with` is misspelled and should be `width`. You don't need to add `px` in width or height, just the svg width and height values.

```
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
```